# What can be done to ensure Stripe and CiviCRM are ready for SCA in Sept 2019

Tags: stripe

There is a comment at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/41#note_14585 saying an MIH will be needed to ensure Stripe+CiviCRM is ready for this.

In Stripe Dashboard is shows

[image]

assuming via API was right option you get

[image]

and assuming i opted for right choice the next screen shows

[image]

and if i add recurring i get

[image]

Comment: also see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31530/sca-compliant-stripe-payments

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Stripe Make it Happen campaign here](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen/stripe-the-next-level).

> - Upgrade to Stripe Elements which simplifies PCI compliance for end-users and allows us to take advantage of the latest developments with Stripe - https://stripe.com/gb/payments/elements
> - Support for SCA Payments - required in Europe for ALL credit card payments from September 2019. To be implemented by migrating to the "PaymentIntents" API: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents
> - Support for processing refunds from within CiviCRM.
> - Support additional payment methods payment methods (eg. SEPA, iDEAL, Google Pay) - once we have switched to Stripe Elements we can implement these easily. If you wish to fund a particular payment method just let us know when you offer funding.

Comment: I have already donated, and for some reason my google search entirely failed to find it. Thx.