# SCA Compliant Stripe Payments

Tags: stripe, financial-accounts, compatiblity

I am working with CiviCRM version **4.6.31** with a modified version of the Stripe Payment Module (to support EU and USA payments separately) found here https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor.

As there have apparently been some changes to the core and custom modules coupled with my newbie status in regard to CiviCRM, an upgrade path is something that is likely to take longer than the time we have available before SCA hits.

I have seen the ["Make it Happen" campaign](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen/stripe-the-next-level) for an updated module and understand it may be available late August (which is cutting it fine!), but am I correct in assuming that this will not be backported to the 4.x branch?

If there is no backport available, are they any other options to become SCA compliant or do I start trying to hack the existing version to use Payment Intents API?

My alternative is to create a separate standalone donation page which then pushes data via the API or even direct DB access.

Any thoughts would be very welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: As an update to this, the consensus from the fine people in the community (thank you) was to perform the necessary upgrades to both the core and modules to bring it in line with the latest CiviCRM version and then use the new Stripe module.